# Convert mmap object (mmaps don't support concatenation) / convert c code to python

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi3, mmap

Hello every one I'm trying to convert below code to python (Accessing the raspberry pi 1Mhz timer), I'm stuck when to mmap object we need to + TIMER_OFFSET (`timer = (long long int *)((char *)st_base + TIMER_OFFSET);`) when I try to do it in Python I got `SystemError: mmaps don't support concatenation`. I was looking for convert mmap object but I find nothing, Can we fight this ?  It is possible to convert whole this code to python? I mean now I have second  thoughts about it ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ST_BASE (0x3F003000)
#define TIMER_OFFSET (4)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long long int t, prev, *timer; // 64 bit timer
    int fd;
    void *st_base; // byte ptr to simplify offset math

    // get access to system core memory
    if (-1 == (fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "open() failed.\n");
        return 255;
    }

    // map a specific page into process's address space
    if (MAP_FAILED == (st_base = mmap(NULL, 4096,
                        PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, ST_BASE))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap() failed.\n");
        return 254;
    }

    // set up pointer, based on mapped page
    timer = (long long int *)((char *)st_base + TIMER_OFFSET); //<- here is problem

    // read initial timer
    prev = *timer;
    // and wait
    sleep(1);

    while (1==1) { // forever
        // read new timer
        t = *timer;
        printf("Timer diff = %lld    \r", prev);
        fflush(stdout);
        // save current timer
        prev = t;
        // and wait
        sleep(1);
    }
    // will never get here
    return 0;
}
```

Python code (for now I skip this ifs) :

```
ST_BASE = 0x3F003000
TIMER_OFFSET = 4
import struct
sizeof_long_long = struct.calcsize('q')

def timer():
    while True:
        fd = os.open("/dev/mem",os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
        stBase = mmap.mmap(fileno=fd,length=4096,offset=ST_BASE)
        timer_bytes = stBase[TIMER_OFFSET:TIMER_OFFSET + sizeof_long_long]
        #print(timer_bytes)
        timer_value, = struct.unpack('q', timer_bytes)
        print(timer_value)
        os.close(fd)
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ok I add python code but there is not a lot

Comment: Thanks. This turned from completely offtopic to rather OK. Also which python version this was?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala 3.4.2

Comment: Try to use the `os.O_RDONLY` only + `mmap(..., prot=PROT_READ)`

Comment: Can't use `prot=PROT_READ` because it is not definied, about `os.O_RDONLY` funny thing before I have `os.O_RDWR` and code was executing (and still is) when I change on `os.O_RDONLY` suddenlny I got `[Errno 13]  permission denied` (which is strange because I run code with "sudo" and `RDONLY<RDWR`)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ok I change `prot=PROT_READ` on `prot=mmap.PROT_READ` and it executes but still I get 0 0 0 0 0...etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost good  :) Just unpack_from instead off unpack

```
import os, mmap, sys
import struct

ST_BASE = 0x3F003000
TIMER_OFFSET = 4
sizeof_long_long = struct.calcsize("Q")
LENGTH = TIMER_OFFSET + sizeof_long_long

def timer():
    fd = os.open("/dev/mem", os.O_RDONLY | os.O_SYNC)
    stBase = mmap.mmap(fileno=fd, length=4096, access=mmap.ACCESS_COPY, offset=ST_BASE)
    os.close(fd)

    while True:
        timer_value = struct.unpack_from("Q", stBase, TIMER_OFFSET)[0]
        print("timer_value")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mmap` object in Python is rather different from pointers in C. The `mmap` object behaves rather like a *bytearray*, with some extra methods. However the bytearray interface is the most useful here. The C code adds an offset to the base address to get a pointer to the first byte of the timer value, then converts this to a pointer to a `long long int`. In Python we can do a similar thing by *slicing* a part of the bytearray, specifically `sizeof (long long int)` bytes starting from the offset, and using the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to decode the value.

Thus we get something like

```
import struct
sizeof_long_long = struct.calcsize('q')

...


    timer_bytes = stBase[TIMER_OFFSET:TIMER_OFFSET + sizeof_long_long]
    print(timer_bytes)

    # struct.unpack would return a tuple of one element, note the comma.
    timer_value, = struct.unpack('q', timer_bytes)
    print(timer_value)
```

Comment: something move on but all the time when I run this code it gives me same value and this should change all the time

Comment: @BengBeng the offset in your Python code is different from the offset in C code?!

Comment: yea I forgot change it in both should be 3F003000 and in my code it is I will edit and put actual code

Comment: About values python gives me all the time : 42949672970 and this c code works like timer and all the time is increasing for now it is : 7446545513

Comment: just like that now python code  stopped print me 42949672970  and just print a lot of "0" and from time to time it print "42949672970 "